# Fill contents from the first filtered cell VISIBLE below

Tags: excel-formula

Please have a look at table 1 and table 2. If I select the filter for C (table 2), I want the cell A1 to be filled with the value that is filtered and present immediatley below A1, that is C (another example is if I select filter for value B, then A1 should be filled with value B ). For this,  I have used this formula for A1  `=INDEX(A2:A5, MATCH(1, SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A5)-ROW(A2),0,1)), 0))`  but it is giving errors. Please help.

[image][image]

Comment: Have you tried entering it as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) (with CTRL+Shift+Enter, instead of just Enter)?

Answer (score 0):

Entering it as an array formula (with CTRL+Shift+Enter, instead of just Enter) worked. That was missing.